# Laravel 5 Auth Redirecting - It works, but is it correct?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Let me try to explain this.

If a guest goes to the `/` directory, he is welcome. If the guest tries to go to the `/start` directory, he is redirected to the log in page.

After a guest logs in, he is redirected to the `/start` directory. If a logged in user goes to the `/` directory, he is again redirected to the `/start` directory. (no need to see home page once logged in).

I got it working how I want, however I'm not sure if I'm doing this how Laravel intends for it to be done being that there is some non-DRY code in my `PagesController.php`. Plus, I'm basically redirecting the PagesController to the PagesController (doesn't sound like that follows good practices to me).

Here is the `routes.php`:

```
<?php

Route::get('', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('start', 'PagesController@start');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
]);
```

Here is the `PagesController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\HowItWorksModel;
use App\WhatYouGetModel;
use App\StartContentModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->action('PagesController@start');
        }

        $howItWorksContent = HowItWorksModel::all();

        $whatYouGetContent = WhatYouGetModel::all();

        return view('pages.index', compact(
            'howItWorksContent',
            'whatYouGetContent'
        ));
    }

    public function start()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $startContent = StartContentModel::all();

            return view('pages.start', compact(
                'startContent'
            ));
        }

        return redirect('/auth/login');
    }
}
```

How can I restructure this to work exactly as it works now but having better practices in mind? Or is what I'm doing perfectly okay for these purposes?

Comment: Perhaps look into [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware), it could very well be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It is better done with [middlewares](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware), using middlewares will take the authentication resposability of your controllers and let it worry about content, this will make your controllers light and maintainable.

You should use [Auth Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#protecting-routes)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. Not much different than what you had but does result in less code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\HowItWorksModel;
use App\WhatYouGetModel;
use App\StartContentModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'index']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::check())
            return redirect('start');

        $howItWorksContent = HowItWorksModel::all();

        $whatYouGetContent = WhatYouGetModel::all();

        return view('pages.index', compact(
            'howItWorksContent',
            'whatYouGetContent'
        ));
    }

    public function start()
    {
       $startContent = StartContentModel::all();

       return view('pages.start', compact(
           'startContent'

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on what the constructor is doing? Never used Middleware before, but I really want to follow good practices so I guess I'll use it now.

Comment: Ah nice I get it now. Thanks again.

Comment: Think of middleware as being between your request and your view. The middleware does the job of making sure the request is appropriate for the view.